# Bootstrap theme for @angular/material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is there a bootstrap theme for `@angular/material` components?
Those components are very good but I'm using `bootstrap` as main framework and don't want to change it to `material`

Comment: Did you check this [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: I want to use angural material code but with bootstrap theme

Comment: No. Angular Material is Material Design. Bootstrap is Bootstrap. If Angular Material looked like Bootstrap, it wouldn't be "Material." You might be interested in [Bootstrap for Angular](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

Comment: may be not for amgular material directly, but in the future there will be space for an angular cdk bootstrap

Comment: found something in this way: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-cdk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts